# Using groups or roles in WSO2 IS AWS SAML

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

Does anybody knows how can I use WSO2 IS Roles or AD groups (throught WSO2 IS) to map AWS ARNs?

https://medium.com/@gayanmadusanka_80721/login-to-aws-console-from-wso2-identity-server-cb05d4d12ff5

I would like to use active directory groups or WSO2 IS roles instead of using mapping claims individually on each user.